# Selecionar apenas algumas colunas do de objetos mapeados com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Como que posso selecionar apenas alguns campos de um objeto relacionado ?

Como funciona (pegando tudo):

```
            List<Participante> participantes = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a "
                + " FROM Participante a WHERE a.pessoa_id = :pessoa "
                + "AND a.motivo_id = :motivo")
                .setParameter("pessoa", pessoa).setParameter("motivo", motivo).getResultList();
```

Como já tentei:

```
            List<Participante> participantes = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT "
                + "new Evento(a.evento_id.id, a.evento_id.nome, "
                + "new Pessoa(a.evento_id.criador_id.id, a.evento_id.criador_id.nome)) "
                + " FROM Participante a WHERE a.pessoa_id = :pessoa "
                + "AND a.motivo_id = :motivo")
                .setParameter("pessoa", pessoa).setParameter("motivo", motivo).getResultList();
```

Com o construtor não apresenta nenhum erro, sem construtor ele me apresenta erro que não foi possível mapear o objeto.

Como transformo meu Participantes em Objetos (o 1 apresentado funciona):

```
    public List<Evento> pegaEventos(List<Participante> participantes) {
    List<Evento> eventos = new ArrayList<Evento>();
    try {
        for(Participante participante : participantes) {
            System.err.println("Evento ID: " + participante.getEvento_id().getId());
            eventos.add(participante.getEvento_id());
        }
        return eventos;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println(junges.getFullStackTrace(e));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Modelo Evento:

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="nome")
private String nome;

@Column(name="descricao")
private String descricao;

@Column(name="preco")
private double preco;

@Column(name="idade")
private int idade;

@Column(name="minpessoas")
private int minpessoas;

@Column(name="maxpessoas")
private int maxpessoas;

@Column(name="dtinicio")
private Timestamp inicio;

@Column(name="dtfim")
private Timestamp fim;

@Column(name="criacao")
private Timestamp criacao;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="categoria")
private Categoria categoria;

@Column(name="endereco")
private String endereco;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="criador_id")
private Pessoa criador_id;

@Column(name="desativado")
private boolean desativado;
```

Modelo Pessoa:

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="nome")
private String nome;

@Column(name="sobrenome")
private String sobrenome;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="senha")
private String senha;

@Column(name="telefone")
private String telefone;

@Column(name="endereco")
private String endereco;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="localizacao")
private Localizacao localizacao;

@Column(name="login")
private Timestamp login;

@Column(name="registro")
private Timestamp registro;

@Column(name="aniversario")
private Timestamp aniversario;

@Column(name="isAdm")
private int isAdm;

@Column(name="desativado")
private boolean desativado;

private double nota;
```

Comment: Você falou que com o construtor das classes `Evento` e `Pessoa` não apresenta erro. Mas funciona? Você consegue pegar os objetos instanciados?

Comment: Tenho um try Catch, que caso der algum erro, ele joga a exibe o erro no console e retorna nullo, se é nullo, a aplicação toda é cancelada

Comment: Sendo assim, ela não chega nem na função retornoListEventos, que lá tem um sysout do id do evento

Comment: Você não consegue colocar um breakpoint e verificar o por que que está dando erro **dentro** do construtor?

Comment: Uma coisa que acho estranha, é que nas outros 2 (Sem construtor e tudo) apresenta o SQL no Console, já com o construtor não. Então, e o mesmo construtor, eu uso em outros lugares.

Comment: Coloquei breakpoint e nada, não apresenta erro nenhum para mim, apenas não exibe o sql

Comment: Talvez você precise colocar o caminho completo da classe quando instanciar com o `new`, observe um exemplo meu : `hql1.append("SELECT new br.com.app.vo.DocumentoVO(...`

Comment: Não funcionou, coloquei: `new br.com.felipejunges.juntos.modelo.Evento( a.evento_id.id, a.evento_id.nome, ...) `

Comment: Você colocou no `new Pessoa(` também? Se bem que você pode colocar essa instanciação **dentro** do método construtor, não precisa chamar pela query.

Comment: Coloquei na query e não no construtor

Comment: Passa todos os atributos pelo construtor, dentro do construtor de Evento você cria a Pessoa.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Não colocar new Pessoa dentro da query, colocar dentro do construtor dentro do Modelo ? Ex: `Evento (int id, ..., new Pessoa(int id)) e dentro dele: this.pessoa = pessoa` ? Ou `Evento(int id, ... pessoa) { this.pessoa = new Pessoa(...) }` ?

Comment: Isso, você passará os parametros de pessoa no construtor (`new br.com.pasta.Evento(id, nome, idPessoa, nomePessoa)`) e dentro do método construtor na classe `Evento` fará o `new Pessoa(idPessoa, nomePessoa)`.

Comment: É não funcionou, ele continua não apresentando nem o SQL no Console... Minha solução temporária é pegar tudo, e na hora de retornar o objeto, eu uso construtores para 'formatar' e passar só parte dessas informações